Error: require() of ES Module not supported. Instead change the require of index.js in
I made this package https://github.com/aliscie/odoc_editor and it was working fine when I implemented it. However, when I run unit tests I get this error

I tried to change tsconfig and vitest
I tried to change the react-dnd version but I got more error
I think it is config issue, because running yarn start does not show any error

